# How to count number of days in back test if start time and end time is taken as input in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I have input as following dates for backtest in a range , how can i calculate the number of days it has in between the start day and end day.

```
start_time              = input(defval=timestamp("1 May 2021 06:00"),   title="Start Time",   
type=input.time)
end_time                = input(defval=timestamp("31 Dec 2021 20:00"),   title="End Time",       
type=input.time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the number of milliseconds between the two dates by the number of milliseconds in one day:

```
days = (end_time - start_time) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```